# How to change complicated function to angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I have a helper function used to bind input with jQuery autocomplete with set of extra options like show bootstrap popover on hover, ability to use secondary label, etc...
I'm facing a problem that my ngModel is not updating when item selected from autocomplete list. This autocomplete select will update text field (for displayed value) and hidden field (for the value). I want to change that to a directive and notify ngModel in text & value fields that item selected.

```
bindAutocomplete: function (textSelector, valSelector, serviceUrl,
    secondaryLabel, minLength, selectCallback,
    tooltipPlacement, showOnTopOfField) {

    if (!tooltipPlacement) {
        tooltipPlacement = "right";
    }

    var autoCOmpletePosition = { my: "left bottom", at: "left top", collision: "flip" };
    if (!showOnTopOfField || showOnTopOfField == false) {
        var autoCOmpletePosition = { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", collision: "none" };
    }

    if (!minLength)
        minLength = 2;

    var jTextSelector = $(textSelector),
        jValSelector = $(valSelector),
        jTextSelectorId = jTextSelector.attr("id");

    jTextSelector.autocomplete({
        source: serviceUrl,
        minLength: minLength,
        position: autoCOmpletePosition,
        select: function (event, ui) {

            jValSelector.val(ui.item.id);

            if (selectCallback) {
                selectCallback(event, ui);
            }
        },
        response: function (event, ui) {
            jQuery.data(jTextSelector[0], jTextSelectorId, ui.content); // Store Filtered result in jQuery data store
        }
    });

    if (secondaryLabel) {

        var uiAutoCompleteData = jTextSelector.data("ui-autocomplete");
        if (uiAutoCompleteData) {
            uiAutoCompleteData._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li>")
                  .append("<a><b>" + item.label + "</b><br><span style='font-size:0.8em;'>" + item.desc + "</span></a>")
                  .appendTo(ul);
            };
        }
    }

    jTextSelector.hover(function () { // On Hover
        bindPopOver(this);
        jTextSelector.popover('show');
    },
    function () { // On Unhover
        jTextSelector.popover('destroy');
    });
    function bindPopOver(element) {
        if (!$(element).val()) {
            jValSelector.val("");
            jTextSelector.popover('destroy');
        }
        else {

            var listContent = jQuery.data(jTextSelector[0], jTextSelectorId); // Get Filtered result from jQuery data store
            var text = jTextSelector.val();

            var item = _.find(listContent, function (itemInList) {
                return itemInList.label.toLowerCase() == text.toLowerCase();
            });

            if (item) {
                jValSelector.val(item.id);
                jTextSelector.popover('destroy');
                jTextSelector.popover({
                    title: text,
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    content: item.desc,
                    placement: tooltipPlacement
                });
            }
            else if (!item && text == "") {
                jValSelector.val("");
                jTextSelector.popover('destroy');
            }
        }
    };
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use directive techniques to transmit data from/to DOM components and angularjs.

I create a simple code with will help us to make the bind.

[plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/Q1HKTNzt1FXGySMrVC0P/preview)

the main rule is the "link" of directive, aided with "scope" definition to reflect external data:

```
scope: { ngMyModel: '=' }

link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('ngMyModel', function (val) {
      el.val(val);
    });
    el.on('change input', function() {
      scope.$apply(function(scope) {
          scope.ngMyModel = el.val();
      });
    });
}
```

Where at first part I reflect on input (or another component, like datepicker, etc) any changes on angularjs data.

At second part, I capture events from element and use "scope.$apply" technique to reflect on angularjs data.

Comment: Yes Exactly, I can now pass any extra param like what you did in ng-my-model .... Thank you for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome! And also, you can use "ngAnotherAttribute": "@" to represent a String non-variable parameter, like a mask or a title.